# Tautological bundle and its dual

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, grassmannians, projective-varieties

Let $X=\mathbb G(2,V)$ be the Grassmannian of $2$-planes in $V=\mathbb C^n$. We denote by $\mathcal S$ the tautological bundle on $X$.
In a paper there is written that "since $\mathcal S$ is a rank 2 bundle, then $\mathcal S(1)=\mathcal S \otimes \mathcal O(1)=\mathcal S^\vee$". Why is this sentence true?

If $X=\mathbb G(k,V)$, can we say that $\mathcal S(k-1)=\mathcal S^\vee$? Or something like that?

Comment: I think this should be because $\mathcal{O}(1)\cong \wedge S^\vee$, and then notice that $V^\vee\cong V\otimes \wedge V^\vee$.

Comment: Where the last isomorphism come from?

Comment: linear algebra.

Comment: the V in my first comment is not the V in your question, it’s an arbitrary 2-dim vector space.

Comment: For the last question: no, this is specific of rank 2. And, by the way, it would be more appropriate on MSE.